# How to solve the side effects probably caused by list.append()?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that ask the user to input students info. to a dictionary, and append each student's info. to a list as below. But the result showed that all the previous data appended are overloaded by the last data.

I can't figure out how the internal operation works in the list. What factor leads the previous data to be overloaded?

```py
student = {"first_name": 0,"last_name": 0,"matriculation_number": 0,
           "course": 0,"university": 0}
student_list = []

def inputStudentData(num):
    dict = student
    for key in dict.keys():
        msg = "Enter no." + str(num) +" student's " + key + ": "
        data = input(msg)
        dict[key] = data
    return dict

def printStudentData(a):
    for i in a:
        print(i)

N = int(input("Enter numbers of students: "))
for i in range(1,N+1):
    student_list.append(inputStudentData(i))

printStudentData(student_list)
```

the result is:

```
Enter numbers of students: 2
Enter no.1 student's first_name: 11
Enter no.1 student's last_name: 1
Enter no.1 student's matriculation_number: 1
Enter no.1 student's course: 1
Enter no.1 student's university: 1
Enter no.2 student's first_name: 2
Enter no.2 student's last_name: 2
Enter no.2 student's matriculation_number: 2
Enter no.2 student's course: 2
Enter no.2 student's university: 2
{'first_name': '2', 'last_name': '2', 'matriculation_number': '2', 'course': '2', 'university': '2'}
{'first_name': '2', 'last_name': '2', 'matriculation_number': '2', 'course': '2', 'university': '2'}
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you're asking, but don't call a dict `dict`

Comment: Define the dictionary inside your `inputStudentData` function. The data is being overwritten because the dictionary is in global scope.

Comment: Because you keep appending the **same** dictionary to your list, because your function, `inputStudentData`, always returns **the same dictionary**. `dict = student` **does not create a copy**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you are overwriting `student` each time you call the function. And in each loop you are appending same instance each time.
- Just look this for an example.

```py
l = []
d = {'a':0,'b':1}
l.append(d)
d['a'] = 100
l.append(d)
d['b'] = 200
l.append(d)
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'a': 100, 'b': 200}, {'a': 100, 'b': 200}, {'a': 100, 'b': 200}]
```

- so you either need to use `copy` or declare your dictionary inside function.

**PS:** Please dont use keywords as variable name. You will run into problems that will haunt you at night. :D

Comment: "And since dictionary in python are mutable you are appending same instance of dict each time." **completely** irrelevant to the semantics here, even if you were appending immutable objects, it would still be the same instance.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i dont think so. Change that dict with something like `int` or `str`

Comment: Of course it does. Python semantics don't change basd on the *type* of the objects. "immutable" objects **simply lack mutator methods** (and indeed, *can* be mutated if you are willing to dig into the python internals, using `ctypes` for example). And yes, try this with, say, a `frozenset`, which is an immutable type: `x = frozenset(['a']); lst = []; list.append(x); list.append(x); print([id(i) for i in lst])`

Answer (score 2):

you need to use use `dict = student.copy()` to get the desired output

why this program behaving like this ?

because you have created a global dictionary student and and in each loop when you call the function and give input, the function take the global dict student  and add value to it and in list.append reference to this dict object is added.

in second loop when you add new data, this global dict got updated and reference to this dict object is added to the list.

so when printing the list, in print function when the iterator in the list goes to the element to print, element points to the value at student dictionary memory location but now at student memory location values are of that last loop. so  for each element same dict object is used, and which is updated for each loop, and it's reference is stored in list. and since each element has same dict object and reference to same mem location you are getting all the value as same.

how to solve this ?

you need to create a shallow copy or deep copy of the dictionary object

Comment: I know how to derive my desired output. But still want to know the reason to this outcome.

Comment: @Hua-MingHuang because **you are appending the same list**

Comment: @Hua-MingHuang i updated the solution and provided the reason